# Why does Eclipse complain about ambiguity in overloaded varargs method?

Tags: eclipse, guava, variadic-functions

My Eclipse (Indigo Service Release 2) complains in Guava's `DoubleMathTest` (current current HEAD, eb89cdb) that the method call

```
DoubleMath.mean(11, -22, 44, -88);
```

is ambiguous. There are exactly the following five methods defined

```
public static double mean(double... values) {...}
public static double mean(long... values) {...}
public static double mean(int... values) {...}
public static double mean(Iterable<? extends Number> values) {...}
public static double mean(Iterator<? extends Number> values) {...}
```

so I really can't see any ambiguity there. Is this an Eclipse bug?

Comment: Hmm. Works fine for me with Kepler. Possibly just an old bug fixed in a later release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be sloved by casting.
Because `Eclipse` can't tell what type your arguments are.
try:
`DoubleMath.mean(11L, -22L, 44L, -88L);`
or
`DoubleMath.mean((int)11, (int)-22, (int)44, (int)-88);`

**EDIT**

If the problem was not solved, it might be a problem/bug that varies at different releases of `Eclipse`.
The code i wrote worked fine for me.  (using `Juno`)
Jon didn't even had a problem with your code (using `Kepler`).
And the problem was partially solved for you when casting to Double. (using `Indigo Service Release 2`).

So it must be related to `Eclipse` release.

Comment: Nothing changes. The arguments are `int`s, even without casting. Using `double` args is the only thing that works.

Comment: I guess the problem varies at different releases of `Eclipse`. The code i wrote worked fine for me. and @Jon didn't even had this problem with your code.

Comment: OK, so it's not really interesting, just an old already-solved bug I couldn't Google-out. Would you mind to update your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Updated. Let me know if you want to add anything to it.